# Multiple digits classifier using MobileNetV1

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, text-classification, mobilenet

I want to train a model to be able to classify 16 number of digits in image, the numbers of digits are constants. So I create my dataset like these images (Print random 16 number with different font and size on SUN dataset background) :

[image]

My training dataset is about 3000 images and 600 images for validation.

So I wanted to use MobileNetV1 as feature extractor and connect to 16 softmax output layers for each digits.

Here is my code snippet to create model

```
base_model = MobileNet(input_shape=None,
                           alpha=0.25,
                           depth_multiplier=1,
                           include_top=False,
                           weights='imagenet,
                           input_tensor=None,
                           pooling=None)

    x = base_model.output
    x = layers.AvgPool2D()(x)
    digits = []
    for i in range(16):
        temp = layers.Conv2D(10, 1, 1, padding='same', name=str(i) + '_digits')(x)

        temp = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(temp)
        digits.append(temp)

    model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=digits)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

so my dataset picture size is (650,65) and train tensor shape is (3000,650,65,3) with normalized values between -1 and 1

and my train labels is 16 arrays of one hot tensors with shape (16,3000,10)

my model compiled successfully and training started but my loss and val_loss is not improved during epochs.

Basically I wanted to create model like this pictures because this model is working great on this digits classification problem.
[image]

The top of this model architecture is something like MobileNetV1 and the input is resizer and normalizer blocks.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the learning rate

Comment: @TT : thanks for response, no I haven’t, I’ll try, just in case does my model seems to be okey?

Comment: @ShayanTabatabaee: I think it can be done effectively using Object Detection than using Image Classification. To know more about Object Detection, You can refer either the link, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection or the link, https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a. In your case, the Bounding Boxes, i.e., the location of First Digit, Second Digit, etc.. will be almost fixed, so that saves lot of effort. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport: Thanks, I'll try it